# Finance Exam: Isn't the solution for this problem wrong?

Tags: interest-rate, calculation, discounting

Hey could you help me out, I think the given solution to this problem is wrong:

Find the present value of $3000 due in 5 years and 6 months if the money is worth 4.5% compounded quarterly.

Solution PV = 2,820.9755

If it´s right could you explain?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Given the parameters in the question, the given answer is wrong. The correct answer should be

`$3000 / (1+4.5%/4)^22 = $2345.4895.`

The given answer would be correct, for example, if the money were due in 1 year and 4.5 months, i.e. 5.5 quarters. Then one would find

`$3000 / (1+4.5%/4)^5.5 = $2820.9755.`

I reckon the person calculating the given answer simply forgot to convert the stated period of time in the question, 5.5 years, to quarters and applied it as is.

Answer (score 1):

As Alper answers, obtaining the correct answer with `r` like so

```
r = (1 + 0.045/4)^(4/2) - 1

3000/(1 + r)^11 = 2345.49
```

`r` is semi-annual interest rate in this version.

Then it looks like a typo to get the expected figure

```
r = (1 + 0.045/4)^(4/8) - 1

3000/(1 + r)^11 = 2820.98
```